# Seemingly simple ball & line collision?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, math, vector

I have a ball accelerating due to gravity 9.81. I also have some lines, which can be moved around and have their slopes changes by the user. How do I handle bouncing collisions between the ball and the lines to make them bounce off at the correct angle. All my collision detection works fine, I was just wondering if there was a way of using the slope of the line to find the resultant vector of the ball after collision.

I am writing in Objective-C with XCode 4 on Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: what is it, any kind of game? if yes, then which game engine you are dealing with?

Comment: It is an iPhone app, but I want to o the physics myself

Comment: I presume you want infinite mass for the lines (so that they are not affected by collision), and perfectly elastic bounces?

Comment: Yes and Yes, well i might have restution of 0.8 or 0.7, but that shouldnt really affect it

Comment: Have you had any luck in implementing the "bouncing" yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the "normal" vector of the "surface" with which the ball collided, and then "flip" the "velocity" vector of the ball accordingly.

To clarify: The "normal" of the line is a perpendicular vector to the line, of unit length. Think of it like: The line represents a plane, which would have a normal vector.

From the top of my head:
Let N be the normalized (unit lenght) "normal" vector of the line, let v be the velocity vector of the ball.

1. Project v onto N using a dot product (p = v DOT N)
2. Add the vector 2*p*N to v (v = v + 2*p*N)

I think that should do the trick...

I would also recommend using a physics engine as already pointed out.

Comment: So basically, let the surface it collides with be flat horizontally, and bouncee the ball by -1 on the y-axis only?

Comment: If the lines are horizontal (dy=0) or vertical (dx=0) it becomes really easy, you just flip the sign of the proper "dimension" of the velocity vector, e.g: the x-part if a vertical line was hit

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered enlisting one of the handful of engines out there to do the dirty work for you? [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) and [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) are three that come to mind.

Comment: Cocos2D is not a phys engine. It contains box2d and chipmunk

Comment: No I am definately not using a physics engine.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it (in my opinion):

- When you create the line calculate the matrix that would rotate it to be horizontal and calculate the inverse of that matrix.
- When the ball collides with the line:

  1. rotate the velocity vector by the rotation matrix
  2. change the sign of the y component
  3. rotate the velocity vector by the inverse of the rotation matrix.

The rotation matrix is given by:

```
( cos A ,  sin A )
( -sin A , cos A )
```

The inverse rotation matrix is given by:

```
( cos A , -sin A )
( sin A ,  cos A )
```

where A is the angle between the line and the horizontal.

The above uses standard mathematical conventions (positive x and y is the upper right quadrant, 0 radians is in the positive direction along the x axis and angles increase anticlockwise.